# Reduce Images loading PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

Through the admin of my image hosting website, I have a page where I can pull up all the images that are uploaded. Issue is, I think it's trying to pull them all and it crashes the site for over 5 mins. How can I limit what loads? I have a tried to see how the User Gallery script is written (since it only loads 15 or so at a time, and you click a button to load more) - but no luck.

I'd like to limit to maybe 50 at a time.

```
<?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="well">
    <h1><?=_('Pictures Administration') ?></h1>
    <?php require_once 'admin-navigation.php'; ?><?php
    if(count($pictures)) {
    ?>
    <table class="table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sortable table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th><?=_('Title') ?></th>
                <th><?=_('User') ?></th>
                <th><?=_('Date') ?></th>
                <th><?=_('Views') ?></th>
                <th><?=_('Server') ?></th>
                <th><?=_('Remove') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            foreach($pictures as $p) {
                $user = ($p->username == NULL) ? 'Guest' : $p->username;

                $image_main = $p->image_name;
                $image_title = htmlentities($p->image_title, ENT_QUOTES);
                $image_path = image_path($p);
                $image_size = getimagesize($image_path);

                if($image_size[0] > 124) {
                    $thumbnail = str_replace("original", "thumbnail", $image_path);
                }else{
                    $thumbnail = $image_path;
                }

                ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="<?=SITE_URL ?>/view-image/<?=$image_main ?>" target="_blank">
            <img alt="" src="<?=$thumbnail ?>" /> </a></td>
            <td><?php echo $image_title ?></td>
            <td><?php if($user != 'Guest') : ?>
            <a href="<?=SITE_URL ?>/user-gallery/<?=$p->username ?>" target="_blank">
            <?=$p->username ?></a><?php else: ?>Guest <?php endif; ?></td>
            <td><?=date("jS F Y", $p->image_date) ?></td>
            <td><?=$p->image_views ?></td>
            <td><?=$p->server ?></td>
            <td>
            <a href="<?=SITE_URL ?>/admin-pictures?remove=<?=$p->imageID ?>">
            <b class="icon-remove-sign"></b></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            } 
            ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    }else{
        echo _("No pictures yet!");
    }
    ?></div>
<?php require_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Post SQL that populates $pictures

Comment: add LIMIT 15 at the back of your SQL query string

Comment: Where would I find this?